# Ember.Select view rendering performance

Tags: performance, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an issue with Ember.Select views taking really long to render. Ember Inspector gives me **rendering times of around 20-30ms** for vanilla built in Ember.Select views (http://emberjs.com/guides/views/built-in-views/). That's fine with one or two Select fields but really adds up when you go beyond a few of them...

Here is an example of a basic Select JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/xawak/10/.

Are there any best practises to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Its an issue of the ember JS select component which unfortunately has up until 1.8.0 still not been resolved. The problem is probably caused by the fact that the component sets up bindings for each option of the select which is an expensive operation.

There is [an issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5259) for this already.