# Ember JS - Improving Performance of Select View

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an select box which contains list of 350-400 `<option>` element. The element data is loaded via ajax. Which loads fine.

But when I ember tries to create the list. The browser hangs with high RAM and CPU uses finally unresponsive script error is shown in browser. Given enough time it renders.

It also seems that ember doesn't really caches the rendered element because every time I comeback to the same page the problem repeats.

So, Is there any way I can improve the performance of the view `select`?

**The sample code for the select view:**

```
{{view "select" prompt="-- select --" content=controllers.application.companies
            optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name_abbr"
            classNames="form-control" value=dailyId}}
```

I know one of the alternatives will be using a typeahead script using a text box. But I want to save it as a plan B for now.

Comment: I have dealt with this before by creating a component that extends it, but I got rid of template and all, and implemented the `render` method, building html "with my own hands" type of thing. Got it under 40ms with around 500 options. I have no idea where I kept that code (replaced mine with select2 instead), but i'll try to find and link here.

Comment: My advice based on past experience: avoid Ember's `select` view. It's slow, it's clunky, and it's outdated. Just write your own component, it'll be well worth it.

Comment: Thank you all! I will try to write a component and see how it performs. @MilkyWayJoe will also have an eye on this Q for your further reply

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.Select view rendering performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069422/ember-select-view-rendering-performance)

Comment: Related ticket https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning**:
This solution is due to be deprecated as of Ember 2.0 according to [this](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/24/another-two-oh-status-update.html#toc_removals) blog entry:

> **REMOVALS**
>
> - ....
> - Manually rendering a string into the buffer in a view

---

I don't think I have an answer for you, and I didn't come back to this 'cause I couldn't find the full implementation I've made a while back. It was essentially a copy of the current select component, except, like I said, I've implemented the `render` method. Something like [**this**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/piduyaguqe/1/edit?html,js,output):

```
App.CustomSelectComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  
  tagName: 'select',
  
  optionValuePath: '',
  
  optionLabelPath: '',
  
  content: [],
  
  render: function(buffer) {
    var selfie = this,
        options = this.get('content'),
        idPath = this.get('optionValuePath'),
        valPath = this.get('optionLabelPath');
    
    options.forEach(function(option) {  
      buffer.push('<option value=\'' +  option[idPath.replace(/^content\.?/, '')] + '\'>');
      buffer.push(option[valPath.replace(/^content\.?/, '')]);
      buffer.push('</option>');
    });
  }
});
```

This is **NOT** the implementation I had before, and if you spend a few seconds looking at it you will see some problems with this solution, *however*, the `render` implementation is what you might want to look into.

With the implementation as is, I can get a better performance already. On the jsbin I've added a small set of records for both `Ember.Select` and the sample custom-select:

[image: A lil faster than built-in ember.select]

But again, this implementation is lacking several features and is probably not enough to answer this question. I just did it a few minutes ago to sort of show were you'd start implementing the `render` and how, within your component.

Sorry if this isn't the answer you wanted.